# Setting State From File Contents

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events, state

I'm trying to set my state variable, to the contents read in from a text file.

Whenever I try to set my state variable within the `r.onload` anonymous function, I get the error that the `setState()` method is not defined.

Which I'm guessing is because of JavaScript's lexical scoping.

I tried binding "this" to a "that" variable and then passing it inside of the `r.onload` anon function and call `that.setState()`, but I still get the same result.

How can I do my `r.onload` anonymous function, and set my state variable once the file contents are read?

React Component:

```
<input type="file" onChange = {this.file} />
```

React Method:

```
file:  function(evt) {
    //Retrieve the first (and only!) File from the FileList object
    var f = evt.target.files[0]; 
    
    if (f) {
      var r = new FileReader();
      r.onload = function(e){ 
          var contents = e.target.result;
          this.setState({ text: contents });
          alert(contents);  
      } 
      r.readAsText(f);
      } else{ 
      alert("Failed to load file");
    }
  }
```

Comment: Where is setState() defined??

Comment: setState() is a React.JS method. I imported it at the beginning of the file. I use it in other methods, and it works within this method, but gets disconnected once I go into the r.onload() function

Comment: Make sure the function is defined before onload()

Comment: It is, I checked it previously

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be because `this` gets redeclared inside your r.onload function, and if your file function is a click event, that might redeclare it too. So try binding both your file and r.onload function

```
file: function(evt) {
    //...
    r.onload = function() {
    //...
    }.bind(this)
}.bind(this)
```